# Vuforia Engine with Hololens Holographic Remoting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

## Background

I have a question about a Unity Framwork which uses the Hololens 2 and Vuforia. The goal is to detect image targets with the Hololens 2 and place objects at this location.

I would like to handle rendering and calculation from the PC, i.e. operate the Hololens via holographic remoting.

Unfortunately, the Hololens does not connect to the Unity application via the IP address (it works in scenarios without Vuforia). Therefore, the hololens is not used at all and the application is started in the Unity Player and the webcam of the notebook is used.

## Question

Is it possible to use Vuforia tracking and Holographic Remoting together and if so how?

#### Edit (30.11)

I have now set up a new project again and tested the Vuforia sample for the Hololens 2 (this time with Unity 2022.3 instead of 2021.3). The remote connection is now established but I only get the holograms on my right eye and additionally the video of my notebook webcam is displayed in my field of view.

Comment: Hololens Remoting does not seem to support streaming the hololens camera. So there does not seem to be a way to offload the Vuforia tracking to the desktop. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/710867/how-to-access-hl2-pv-camera-by-holographic-remotin .

Comment: Regarding rendering it might be possible to use the Azure Remote Rendering but please see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/remote-rendering/how-tos/unity/holographic-remoting

Comment: @emay Thanks for the links, it definitely looks like the Hololens camera output is not being passed correctly as the output and image target detection is not working. I can now get a remote connection but only see the holograms on one eye and additionally the output of my webcam overlaid (see edit).